# Authenticate mvc controller then redirect from angular to mvc path

Tags: angular, asp.net-mvc, angular-routing

We are using ASP.NET MVC with razor but some of pages are in angular 12. cause we are migrating gradually from ASP.NET MVC to Angular 12.

In this we have authenticated user from an ASP.NET MVC controller by post request with token, returning true when authenticated else false.

In ASP.NET MVC I am using Forms authentication.

I have this code in my controller:

```
public ActionResult AuthenticateUser(LoginModel loginmodel)
{
    // some code to validate user
    // loginmodel.token -> valid token 
    // loginmodel.examid -> valid exam id
    //FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(userLogin.UserName, false);
    FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(userLogin.UserName, false);
    // BY using this line we are directing user to dashboard once authenticated

    return Json(true);            // user is authenticated
else  
    return Json(false);
}
```

In Angular after serving request (following code is request by Angular to above C# code)

```
 this.myService.AuthenticateUser(this.examid,token).pipe(first()).subscribe(data => {
   data = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data));

   if (data == true) 
   {
       window.location.href = "https://localhost/dashboard"
   }
   else
       window.location.href = "https://localhost/login"
})
```

It is not redirecting to dashboard instead of it is showing following error

[Error shown in console from angular](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dSDCh.png)

For me it looks like angular is trying to parse response instead of redirecting by window.location.href . is there am i missing some thing in this ?

Update:

if i remove this line from controller `FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(userLogin.UserName, false);` then angular is redirecting to dashboard but it refuses connection / authentication even if i added this  `FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie`.

[image for illustration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tiXLJ.png)

Comment: You can use angular router for redirecting to different route

Comment: Look in the network tab, what is the actual result being returned from the call? Is this valid json? If you do want to return text like `true` or `false` as a string then you need to specify that text is being returned and not json (the default).

Comment: It looks like your server isn't setup correctly. What content do you get back if you directly paste https://localhost/login in your browser and hit enter?

Comment: @Igor it is returning html cause, MVC is `RedirectFromLoginPage` which is redirecting to dashboard but angular processing it as response and trying to parse into json

Comment: @MikeOne it will redirect to login screen created in mvc c# razor